# .Net 6 WebApi passing array of int as parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to pass an array of int to the Controller but I'm getting empty array every time. I know I have to use [FromQuery]. What I'm doing wrong?

```
        [HttpGet("top10/{lineId}/{dateTo}/{groupingType}/{lathes}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTop10(byte lineId, DateTimeOffset dateTo, string groupingType, [FromQuery] int[] lathes)
    {
        // some stuff
    }
```

And my URL looks like that:

> https://localhost:44439/api/v1/dashboards/overview/top10/1/2022-09-28/days/lathes=2&lathes=3&lathes=4&lathes=6

Comment: I think your array has to be part of the querystring proper (after the ?)... not part of the route.

Comment: @TGnat You are correct, thanks for help, all works when I remove it from HttpGet and add ? insted of /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **FromQuery** attribute "Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using the request query string." [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

So the issue is that you are including the `lathes` in the route but asking the framework to read it from the query string.

Specify the endpoint route as this:

```
[HttpGet("top10/{lineId}/{dateTo}/{groupingType}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTop10(byte lineId, DateTimeOffset dateTo, string groupingType, [FromQuery] int[] lathes)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

And add the lathes as query string ("?")

```
https://localhost:44439/api/v1/dashboards/overview/top10/1/2022-09-28/days?lathes=2&lathes=3&lathes=4&lathes=6
```